# Does === exist in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I'm aware of the `===` operator in PHP which connotes not only value equality, but type matching also i.e.

```
if (20 === "20") //false
```

Is there something similar in javascript if I'm using jquery? Examples code could help too.

Thanks

Comment: It exists in javascript. You can open a firebug console to check (if you're using firefox and have firebug installed).

Comment: Wouldn't have been easy to try it out on some test page, open it up in a browser, and see if it threw some sort of error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes the operator exists in javascript.  jQuery is just a framework built with javascript so all of the javascript syntax and operators are still there.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is part of the JavaScript language. `===` and `==` are the same except that `==` will try to convert the types while `===` will not.

Answer (score 4):

JQuery is a Javascript library. The "==" operator does indeed exist in Javascript. If you want strict equality, you should use the "==="  operator.

http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/stricteq.html

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript behavior of `===` is very similar to php - check for equality and same type.
This is not jQuery by the way - jQuery is a JavaScript framework. Basically, it's a group for JavaScript functions. It isn't the language.

Answer (score 2):

According to an article on [Net Tuts](http://www.netTuts.com) by [jeffrey way](http://jeffrey-way.com/)  titled "24 JavaScript Best Practices"
that recommends:

"JavaScript utilizes two different kinds of equality operators: `=== | !==` and `== | !=` It is considered best practice to always use the former set when comparing."

Obviously the same rule applies when using jQuery.

see the article here: [24 JavaScript Best Practices](http://tinyurl.com/l99w56)